# Struts Disabled field

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1

I need to disable a dropdown on jsp page when it loads.However the html element will not be posted if it is disabled.I tried using a hidden element with the same id as the html element it still does not post the element.I am using struts.Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks
Minu

Answer (score 1):

Your approach was good but you didn't use the proper attribute. The `name` is sent on the request not the `id` attribute.

Here is a simple example on how to do it (save this in a file named `t.html`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableCombo() {
        var combo = document.getElementById("comboId");
        var txt = document.getElementById("txtId");
        combo.disabled = true;
        txt.value = combo.value;
    }
</script>
```

and then...

```
<body onload="javascript:disableCombo();">
    <form method="get" action="t.html">
        <select name="comboName" id="comboId">
            <option value="v1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="v2" selected="selected">Value 2</option>
            <option value="v3">Value 3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="comboName" id="txtId" value="waiting to see what happens" />
        <input type="submit" value="watch the address bar" />
    </form>
</body>
```

When you press submit, the value of the combo (already copied in the hidden field when you disabled the combo on load) is sent on the request.

Comment: I tried doing that still the value is not getting posted.
Below is my code:
<div id="StateField">
<html:select property='State' styleId='State' altKey='r1.state.label' >
<html:optionsCollection name="${Constants.STATESLIST}" />
</html:select>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="State" id="State1" />
Onload i m calling:
 function disableDropDown()
  {
  var state = document.getElementById('State');
  var state1 = document.getElementById('State1');
      state1.value = state.value;
       state.disabled = true;
  }

Comment: @user573010: Your JSP code looks OK. It should work. I guess it must be something in the HTML that is generated from it. Check to see if you have any errors in the JavaScript console, if your fields are inside a form (can't submit without a form), see if you have <options> in your page (maybe ${Constants.STATESLIST} didn't resolve properly). In short, check your HTML.